# Position of SlidingDrawer handle?

Tags: android, layout, slidingdrawer

I would like to have two overlapping SlidingDrawers (spanning the whole application window) with their handles side by side so that the user can open both drawers easily.
However, it seems that the handle is always positioned horizontally centered (for a vertical SlidingDrawer) so that the handles collide. I tried both FrameLayout and RelativeLayout for the parent, but layout options like android:layout_alignRight seem to be ignored for the handles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems not to be possible. I decided not to use SlidingDrawers but "normal" buttons which will open the additional views.